# Python Trueskill - Using Dictionaries

Tags: python, arrays, list, dictionary, tuples

I'm trying out the [Trueskill](http://trueskill.org/) package from Python and have the basics worked out,

For a two player match up I can do

```
alice = Rating()
bob = Rating()
alice, bob = rate_1vs1(alice, bob)
```

And for multiple player matchups I can do

```
alice = Rating()
bob = Rating()
eve = Rating()

alice, bob, eve = rate([(alice,),(bob,),(eve,)], ranks=[0, 1, 2])
```

I currently have a database with is structured as follows which I'd like to perform ratings on...

```
game participant rank ....(various game stats)
1    alice       2
1    bob         1
1    eve         3
2    alice       1
2    eve         1
3    bob         1
3    carol       2
3    alice       3
3    ted         4
3    eve         5
.......
```

This is a simplified version as some of the games feature 2 participants, some up to 20.  What I want to do is read through the database game by game, reading the participants in and performing updates based on the results.  I'm not sure of the best way to do this as I know dynamically creating variables is a big no - but what's the right way?

-- EDIT, USING DICTIONARY --

So using dictionaries I can do

```
ratings = {}
k = 0
for participant in results:
    ratings[k] = Rating
    k += 1
```

However I can't figure out how to rate the players, as the following doesn't work as the dictionary would be a rating group, rather than individual participants

```
new_ratings = rate(ratings.values(),ranks=[0-k])
```

Comment: I can see how to store the ratings in a dictionary using ratings[k] = Rating() but I can't see how to reference the dictionary items when performing the rating update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did similar thing for applying to a TV show: https://gist.github.com/sublee/4967876

`defaultdict` and `groupby` may help you to achieve what you want:

```py
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import groupby
from pprint import pprint
from trueskill import Rating, rate

results = [(1, 'alice', 2),
           (1, 'bob', 1),
           (1, 'eve', 3),
           (2, 'alice', 1),
           (2, 'eve', 1),
           (3, 'bob', 1),
           (3, 'carol', 2),
           (3, 'alice', 3),
           (3, 'ted', 4),
           (3, 'eve', 5)]
ratings = defaultdict(Rating)

for game_id, result in groupby(results, lambda x: x[0]):
    result = list(result)
    rating_groups = [(ratings[name],) for game_id, name, rank in result]
    ranks = [rank for game_id, name, rank in result]
    transformed_groups = rate(rating_groups, ranks=ranks)
    for x, (game_id, name, rank) in enumerate(result):
        ratings[name], = transformed_groups[x]

pprint(dict(ratings))
```

The result I got:

```
{'alice': trueskill.Rating(mu=23.967, sigma=4.088),
 'bob': trueskill.Rating(mu=36.119, sigma=5.434),
 'carol': trueskill.Rating(mu=29.226, sigma=5.342),
 'eve': trueskill.Rating(mu=16.740, sigma=4.438),
 'ted': trueskill.Rating(mu=21.013, sigma=5.150)}
```

Comment: Heungsub - is there a way to modify this to allow for teams of multiple participants?

Comment: Use `[(r1, r2), (r3, r4, r5)]` for `rating_groups` instead of `[(r1,), (r2,), (r3,), (r4,), (r5,)]`.

Comment: @HeungsubLee Thanks for your fantastic implementation of the TrueSkill algo. I have asked and answered my own question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60785368/most-efficient-way-to-use-trueskill-algo-to-backfill-a-dataset-in-pandas/60807604#60807604, its similar to your solution I think, except it uses Pandas. If you are in lockdown and have some time, would you mind perusing it to tell me what you think. Kind regards, Luke