# Most efficient way to use TrueSkill Algo to backfill a dataset in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the [following gist](https://gist.github.com/lukebyrne/97e77cf57374f49a75d2914532b2adde) that implements the [TrueSkill](https://trueskill.org/) algorithm over a dataset that is a collection n-player free-for-all games, where there is a winner, then second, third, fourth place etc.

Basically what I am asking is:

- Have I implemented the algo correctly
- Whats the most efficient way to backfill data in a Pandas dataframe

Comment: I have just found this thread from the creator of the library https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723975/python-trueskill-using-dictionaries

Comment: So based on the above comment, I think I am almost there in my code, rather than writing back to the Pandas DataFrame I think its more efficient to just create an array of dictionaries and then append that back onto the DataFrame. I will have a play with it myself a bit later on today.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution:

```
# Fetch the data
df = pd.read_csv('http://horse-data-abcd.s3.amazonaws.com/game_results.csv')
#sample_df = df[df['game_id'].isin([1592008, 1592012, 1592238, 1500903])].copy()
sample_df = df.head(10000)


def rate_games(df):

    # store ratings for each user, this way it is easier to keep track of Rating between games
    # i've decided that it will be easier compared to earlier implementation
    # Ratings are initialized with default values mu=25.0 sigma=8.333
    trueskills = {user_id: Rating() for user_id in df['player_id'].unique()}

    # Group by the game_id
    games = df.sort_values('date').groupby('game_id')
    dataframes_list = []

    # Now iterate the games
    for game_id, game in games:  

        # sorting by postion (from best to last) this way rate function will figure out which player was best automatically
        sorted_players = game.sort_values('position').iterrows()
        # rate function allows input in form of [{some_label: Rating}, ...] and also it will return list
        # in the same form with new Ratings. having [{row_id: Rating}, ...] will allow merging back the rating data
        # back into original dataframee
        trueskills_dicts = [{index: trueskills.get(row['player_id'], Rating())} for index, row in sorted_players]
        flat_trueskill_dict = dict(ChainMap(*trueskills_dicts))

        # Get the results from the rate method
        try:
            results = rate(trueskills_dicts)  # returns [{'row_id': new rating}, ...]
        except ValueError:
            results = trueskills_dicts

        # This converts results list of dicts into dict
        # {'row_id_1': rating, 'row_id_2': rating}
        flat_results_dict = dict(ChainMap(*results))

        # This section prepares small dataframe looking like this, sorted from best to worst:
        # index | mu | sigma | post_mu | post_sigma
        # 3245  | 25 | 8.33  | 27.0    | 5.0
        # 1225  | 25 | 8.33  | 26.0    | 5.0
        df_columns = defaultdict(list)
        df_index = []
        for index, new_rating in flat_results_dict.items():
            df_index.append(index)
            previous_rating = flat_trueskill_dict.get(index, Rating())
            df_columns['mu'].append(previous_rating.mu)
            df_columns['sigma'].append(previous_rating.sigma)
            df_columns['post_mu'].append(new_rating.mu)
            df_columns['post_sigma'].append(new_rating.sigma)

        # this dataframe has the same index column as the main one
        # because of that we will be able to easily join it at the end of the function
        df_results = pd.DataFrame(
            df_columns,
            index=df_index
        )
        dataframes_list.append(df_results)

        # ok, all calclulations done, lets update the trueskills and advance to the next game
        trueskills.update({game.loc[index, 'player_id']: rating for index, rating in flat_results_dict.items()})

    # last thing get list of dataframes with calculated ratings and join it with main dataframe
    concatenated_df = pd.concat(dataframes_list)    
    df = df.join(concatenated_df)
    df.loc[:, 'player_id'].fillna(0, inplace=True)
    return df

sample_df = rate_games(sample_df)
sample_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have come up with, can probably be optimised for speed.

```
# Fetch the data
df_raw = pd.read_csv('http://horse-data-abcd.s3.amazonaws.com/game_results.csv')

# Create a holding DataFrame for our TrueRank
df_truerank_columns = ['game_id', 'player_id', 'position', 'mu', 'sigma', 'post_mu', 'post_sigma']
df_truerank = pd.DataFrame(columns=df_truerank_columns)

# Use a sample of 1000
df = df_raw.head(10000)

# Group by the game_id
games = df.groupby('game_id')

# Now iterate the games
for game_id, game in games:
    # Setup lists so we can zip them back up at the end
    trueskills = []    
    player_ids = []
    game_ids = []  
    mus = []    
    sigmas = []
    post_mus = []
    post_sigmas = []

    # Now iterate over each player in a game
    for index, row in game.iterrows():

        # Create a game_ids arary for zipping up
        game_ids.append(game_id)

        # Now push the player_id onto the player_ids array for zipping up
        player_ids.append(int(row['player_id']))

        # Get the players last game, hence tail(1)
        filter = (df_truerank['game_id'] < game_id) & (df_truerank['player_id'] == row['player_id'])                            
        df_player = df_truerank[filter].tail(1)

        # If there isnt a game then just use the TrueSkill defaults
        if (len(df_player) == 0):
            mu = 25
            sigma = 8.333
        else:
            # Otherwise get the mu and sigma from the players last game
            row = df_player.iloc[0]
            mu = row['post_mu']
            sigma = row['post_sigma']

        # Keep lists of pre mu and sigmas
        mus.append(mu)
        sigmas.append(sigma)

        # Now create a TrueSkull Rating() class and pass it into the trueskills dictionary
        trueskills.append(Rating(mu=mu, sigma=sigma))

    # Use the positions as ranks, they are 0 based so -1 from all of them
    ranks = [x - 1 for x in list(game['position'])]

    # Create tuples out of the trueskills array
    trueskills_tuples = [(x,) for x in trueskills]

    try:
        # Get the results from the TrueSkill rate method
        results = rate(trueskills_tuples, ranks=ranks)

        # Loop the TrueSkill results and get the new mu and sigma for each player
        for result in results:
            post_mus.append(round(result[0].mu, 2))
            post_sigmas.append(round(result[0].sigma, 2))        
    except:
        # If the TrusSkill rate method blows up, just use the previous 
        # games mus and sigmas
        post_mus = mus
        post_sigmas = sigmas

    # Change the positions back to non 0 based
    positions = [x + 1 for x in ranks]

    # Now zip together all our lists 
    data = list(zip(game_ids, player_ids, positions, mus, sigmas, post_mus, post_sigmas))

    # Create a temp DataFrame the same as df_truerank and add data to the DataFrame
    df_temp = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=df_truerank_columns)

    # Add df_temp to our df_truerank
    df_truerank = df_truerank.append(df_temp)
```